# "Local compilation failed. .Net cannot load runtime assembly '<dllname>.dll'." has a length of 85, differs near "Loc" (index 0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

I am facing the below error while running some unit test cases.

Result Message:
Expected syntaxError to be
"" with a length of 0, but
"Local compilation failed. .Net cannot load runtime assembly 'dllname.dll'." has a length of 85, differs near "Loc" (index 0).

Was facing the same issue in the actual code also but it got resolved by adding
hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" to the web.config file.

However the same is not working when added to the app.config file in the tests project.
Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Looks like a failed assert in your unit test. Impossible to tell more without some more details.

Comment: @KlausGütter: It is not an assertion fail. The API that I am invoking gives the error that it is unable to load the dll

Comment: That *really* looks like a test assertion failure (the "has a length of 85, differs near "Loc") part - it looks like you're expecting no syntax errors, but the failure to load the DLL is causing `syntaxError` to be set. Without a [mcve] it's going to be very hard to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes you are right, the test case as such fails as it expects no syntax errors, whereas the API I invoke from the 3rd party package is returning the above error.
Not really sure how I can create a minimal reproducible example for the same.
The same package works fine with the actual code but fails only when its invoked via the unit test.

Comment: Well can't you cut it down to a single unit test that does nothing but call the API from the 3rd party package, and show us that? (Aside from anything else, that would at least remove the part where it's a unit test assertion error rather than the actual exception being thrown.) Why wouldn't that be a  minimal example? Is the 3rd party package a freely-available one?

Comment: Sure, let me do that and add the details in the question.